# Bootstrap 4 - heading / p tags not displaying as block?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Running into an issue where heading tags are not displaying as block elements when using Bootstrap 4.  This doesn't happen when I use Bootstrap 3.

Likewise images that are aligned using either css or the align tag are not floating properly.

[image]
Here is the Bootstrap 4 test: https://www.bootply.com/2ENIt1Dlhl

Here is the Bootstrap 3 test (which displays properly): https://www.bootply.com/bV3lwrQ2L0

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add `d-block` to `row` will fix the issue.

Bootstrap 4 by default row displays as `flex` so `d-block` overwrite it as `display: block!important;`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-block">
        // your code
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/8QXExi07Ha

Answer (score 1):

What Znaneswar say is correct. But u can also use the bootstrap4 class `flex-column`

```
<div class="container flex-column">
    <div class="row d-block">
        // your code
    </div>
</div>
```